# How can I get all the id properties of the different element inside a <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, properties

Let's suppose that on my web page I have a `<div>` with the different tags inside such as `<p>`, `<label>`, `<span>` and whatsoever, all of them has a unique id property. On javascript, how can I get the id's of the elements inside a `<div>`?

For example:

```
<div id = "cont">

<p id = '0001'>
Prod One
</p>

<label id = '0002'>
Prod Two
</label>


<p id = '0003'>
Prod Three
</p>


<span id = '0004'>
Prod Four
</span>


</div>

<button onclick = 'getIDsInsideDiv()'>Get The ID of the elements inside the div </button>
```

If I'm going to click the button, it will output:

```
0001, 0002, 0003, 0004
```

Comment: What is your use case and more importantly what have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `querySelectorAll` to perform a query based on a CSS-style selector.

Here I would use `#cont [id]` to get all elements with an `id` attribute that are a child of `#cont`.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#cont [id]'),
    ids = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function(element) {
        return element.id;
    });
```

Keep in mind that this is a recursive search for elements under `#cont`. If you don't want to retrieve nested elements (ie, you only want immediate children), use `#cont > [id]`.

I'm using `Array.prototype.map.call` here as the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` is like an array but doesn't have the methods like `map()`. See [*NodeList - Why is NodeList not an Array?*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_is_NodeList_not_an_Array)

JSFiddle demo ~ http://jsfiddle.net/qykfv6Lp/